# php error in insert file byte code in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a big problem

when i try to put the query string in the file the following error appears

**Incorrect string value: '\ XE6 \ x00 \ x00 \ xfd \ xfd \ xfd ...'**

````
INSERT INTO `web_plugins` (`nome`, `xmllocal_nome`, `icone_url`, `icone_bytecode`, `swf_url`, `swf_bytecode`) VALUES ('asdfasdf', 'wqwerrwe', '/assets/uploads/plugins_icons/f2d2d3d9.gif', 'GIF89a\0\0ï¿½\0\0ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½~~~}}}|||{{{zzzyyywwwvvvuuutttsssrrrqqqpppooonnnmmmjjjfffdddbbb```___]]]\\\\\\ZZZYYYXXXWWWRRRQQQCCC@@@888ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0!ï¿½\0\0Q\0,\0\0\0\0\0\0\0ï¿½ï¿½\'KP?BI2/?\02G&-*8\'+;\rNL:!.\"%)\"\'&\'-=B!1)$(%&$ï¿½1H;+\',-(&%%#ï¿½!4\Z\'))ï¿½Ôº(##!94)*$#ï¿½\'*&# \"#-/\'\"ï¿½ï¿½$! <>!$!!\"HPï¿½ï¿½ï¿½2>ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½_ï¿½ï¿½pï¿½ï¿½ï¿½cï¿½ï¿½,ï¿½Hï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½6Fï¿½:ï¿½Qr+4ï¿½0aFï¿½bï¿½Lï¿½8ï¿½ï¿½ \nï¿½ï¿½ï¿½b&ï¿½]ï¿½Øï¿½Iï¿½
````

Comment: What type is the column `swf_bytecode`? What character set are you using? (I suggest UTF-8.)

Comment: @showdev the encoding should be irrelevant, `swf_bytecode` should be really a `BLOB`.

Comment: is not swf_bytecode, is icone_bytecode, I am already using UTF-8

Comment: the type field in db is mediumtext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the gif in a BLOB column.

Imagine the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE testblob(
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  data MEDIUMBLOB,
  PRIMARY KEY ( id )
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Then you can use the following INSERT code:

```
<?php
    $dbh = mysql_connect("localhost", "user");
    mysql_select_db("test");
    $data = file_get_contents("your.gif");
    // This is important to avoid a ' to accidentally close a string
    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO testblob(data) VALUES ('$data')");
?>
```

Note that this is taken from an [article](http://www.it-iss.com/mysql/mysql-inserting-and-reading-blobs-in-php/) from the web. Thanks to the author.

Further you should note, that the mysql_* extension has been marked deprecated. You should use the PDO or mysqli extension instead. I personally prefer PDO. Here comes an example that uses PDO:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

// create a prepared statement
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `testblob` (`data`) VALUES (:data)');    
// assign the blob value to it
$stmt->bindParam(1, file_get_contents('your.gif'), PDO::PARAM_LOB);

// execute the statemt
$stmt->execute();
```